# How to insert a new values pair in an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I've an associative array. I am attempting to create each sub array within a loop and insert it into a multidimensional array. Google suggested using array_merge, but after using 'print_r' on the multidimensional array with the code below, only the last sub-array is being displayed.

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [candidate] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 184
                            [firstName] => skg
                            [lastName] => s
                            [address] => Array
                                (
                                    [address1] => sakthi
                                    [address2] => 
                                    [city] => 
                                    [state] => 
                                    [zip] => 
                                    [countryID] => 1
                                    [countryName] => United States                                                   
                                    [countryCode] => US
                                )

                            [hourlyRate] => 0
                        )

                    [jobOrder] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 88
                            [title] => Tech Analyst
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [candidate] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 852
                            [firstName] => mso cool     
                            [lastName] => 
                            [address] => Array
                                (
                                    [address1] => 
                                    [address2] => 
                                    [city] => 
                                    [state] => 
                                    [zip] => 
                                    [countryID] => 1
                                    [countryName] => United States                                                   
                                    [countryCode] => US
                                )

                            [hourlyRate] => 0
                        )

                    [jobOrder] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 57
                            [title] => Tester
                        )

                )
```

**And Another Array like this :**

```
[rating] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 
    )
```

**How to get merge this array value into previous array values like**

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [candidate] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 184
                            [firstName] => skg
                            [lastName] => s
                            [address] => Array
                                (
                                    [address1] => sakthi
                                    [address2] => 
                                    [city] => 
                                    [state] => 
                                    [zip] => 
                                    [countryID] => 1
                                    [countryName] => United States                                                   
                                    [countryCode] => US
                                )

                            [hourlyRate] => 0
                    [rating] => 7
                        )

                    [jobOrder] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 88
                            [title] => Tech Analyst
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [candidate] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 852
                            [firstName] => mso cool     
                            [lastName] => 
                            [address] => Array
                                (
                                    [address1] => 
                                    [address2] => 
                                    [city] => 
                                    [state] => 
                                    [zip] => 
                                    [countryID] => 1
                                    [countryName] => United States                                                   
                                    [countryCode] => US
                                )

                            [hourlyRate] => 0
                            [rating] => 5
                        )

                    [jobOrder] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 57
                            [title] => Tester
                        )

                )
```

I tried lot of tricks but couldn't get the desired array format. Can any one help me in this to get the desired array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your `tricks`

Comment: @u_mulder $response = array_merge($response,$canDetails);

Comment: There is no way to merge it with simple `array_merge` function. You can iterate and insert additional info from second array - it would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = array(); //filled with data
$rating = array(); //filled with rates

foreach ( $rating as $key =>$rate ) {
    $arr['data'][ $key ]['rating'] = $rate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr=Array(
    'data'=>Array(
        0=>Array('candidate'=>Array()),
        1=>Array('candidate'=>Array())
    )
);

$rating=Array(7,5);

foreach($rating as $key=>$val){
    $arr['data'][$key]['rating']=$val;
}

print_r($arr);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [candidate] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [rating] => 7
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [candidate] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [rating] => 5
                )

        )

)
```